# array can't read data from plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, plist

I have found couple of similar topic about this but none of them solve my problem.
basically I want to read nsstring from my array in plist and then I want to overwrite the nsstring value.

```
NSArray *directoriespaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDir = [directoriespaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullnamefordir = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];

        NSArray *turns = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:fullnamefordir];
        NSString *resultofarray = [turns objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%@",turns); 
        NSLog(@"%@",resultofarray);
```

nslog always shows null and i'm not trying to save anything so far because i can't even read the value :/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>8</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

i also tried with nsdictionary but it also doesn't work
thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Check whether your plist file exist in Document Directory or not.

```
NSFileMangaer *objFileManager=[[NSFileManager alloc]init];
BOOL isfileExist=[objFileManager fileExistsAtPath:yourDocumentDirectoryPath];
```

IF Bool Value is true then check you content of plist.
May be the file doesnt exist in document directory ,it is in resource.
If you didnot copied you plist from resource folder to document directory then first copy it there and then try to access it.

Comment: nslog shows that file does exist. What do you mean by copying file from resources to document directory, where can i find this folder?

Comment: Check your document Directory for your plist file. YourUsername->Library->ApplicationSupport->IphoneSimulator->5.0->ChooseApplicationID->Documents      
If there are many applications availabel delete all and run the application..only one applciation will be there and then check the document directory.

Comment: like you said, i deleted all application documents and i build my app once again. strange thing is that now my plist file doesn't exist in Documents and also nslog shows that the file doesn't exist. what should i do in this case? by the way thank you for your replies.

Comment: It means your plist file is in resourceFolder copy first it into document directory before starting any manipulation.
    NSString *resourcePathPlist= [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                    pathForResource:@"data"
                                             ofType:@"plist"];
check for existence of this path .The using fileManager object copy it to documentFolder.
[fileManagerObject copyItemAtPath:resoucePlistPath
                                        toPath:documentDirectoryPath
                                         error:&err];

Comment: perfect! now everything works as i wanted. one last question, i update content of my plist in code and everything works, but if i'll do it in Xcode in the graphical interface it seems like plist file doesn't update itself automatically. is there any way to update plist file in Xcode and in the documents to show the same values? anyway thanks a lot, you saved my day :)

Comment: You cannot update the file which is in your application bundle. Application Bundle file are read only.To edit it you have to copy it to documents and start your operation.The file you see in xcode are in Application Bundle,you can edit it in xcode but while running the app you cant edit it,that is read only.